Not able to migrate using nkdAgility, getting group name already exists in scope error
I am migrating my project from one organization to another, while migrating, getting below error as the group already exists in the scope -

Please let me know if you need more information.
I tried reading the documentation of the tool but still not able to solve it.

Please share your configuration.json of migration(remove token) for checking. As per the error, the group/team mapping seems not mapping correctly. I will share my configuration.json sample with teams sync ahead for your reference below.

As per the error message, the group (XXX team) already exists in target, which is not mapped.
Below is my configuration.json, it synced teams and validate user mapping for TfsWorkItemMigrationProcessor, which is working on my side.
Please follow TfsTeamSettingsTool and Processors block for a check.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information"
  },
  "MigrationTools": {
    "Version": "16.0",
    "Endpoints": {
      "Source": {
        "EndpointType": "TfsTeamProjectEndpoint",
        "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/sourceorg/",
        "Project": "wadetest16",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "ReflectedWorkItemIdField": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "Authentication": {
          "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
          "AccessToken": "PAT"
        },
        "LanguageMaps": {
          "AreaPath": "Area",
          "IterationPath": "Iteration"
        }
      },
      "Target": {
        "EndpointType": "TfsTeamProjectEndpoint",
        "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/targetorg/",
        "Project": "wadetest17",
        "TfsVersion": "AzureDevOps",
        "Authentication": {
          "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
          "AccessToken": "PAT"
        },
        "ReflectedWorkItemIdField": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "LanguageMaps": {
          "AreaPath": "Area",
          "IterationPath": "Iteration"
        }
      }
    },
    "CommonTools": {
      "TfsGitRepositoryTool": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Mappings": {
          "test1": "test1"
        }
      },
      "TfsRevisionManagerTool": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "ReplayRevisions": true,
        "MaxRevisions": 0
      },
      "TfsTeamSettingsTool": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "MigrateTeamSettings": true,
        "UpdateTeamSettings": true,
        "MigrateTeamCapacities": true,
        "Teams": [ "wadetest16 Team", "Team2" ]
      }
    },
    "Processors": [
      {
        "ProcessorType": "TfsWorkItemMigrationProcessor",
        "Enabled": true,
        "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
        "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
        "WIQLQuery": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan','Shared Steps','Shared Parameter','Feedback Request') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc",
        "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
        "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
        "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
        "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
        "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
        "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
        "SourceName": "Source",
        "TargetName": "Target",
        "MaxGracefulFailures": 0,
        "SkipRevisionWithInvalidIterationPath": false,
        "SkipRevisionWithInvalidAreaPath": false
      }
    ]
  }
}



Thanks, it actually worked. I was using a processor 'TfsTeamSettingsProcessorOptions' hoping that it will migrate the team settings. But I think putting this in common tools, worked. I spent lot of time to read the documentation to understand how to do it correctly, but I guess there is still lot to learn.

Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!
